# Git add remote on different directory layout

Tags: git

My company has forked some github projects internally, and I am tasked with reconnecting them to the original projects, and eventually contributing back. At this point, the nature of these projects is not relevant, just that there has been significant development both on github and in the forked codebase, so merging won't be trivial.

In one specific case, I'm facing a weird scenario, where the gh project is hierarchic, but my company repo is flat.

Let's say the github repo URL is https://github.com/someorg/somerepo.git .
Unfortunately, our repo points to the "someorg" level, and has a "somerepo" folder inside.

I would like to add the gh project as a remote and pull changes, but those changes would be applied on the wrong directory level. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: `git subtree` might be the command (family) you're looking for.

Comment: @Zeta thanks. I looked into it, but there doesn't seem to be a way to attach a remote to a subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to keep both folder structures. One of you will have to change. If the change in folder structure (to match your layout) is a good one, then raise a pull request. Otherwise, you will have to restructure your folders.

You can use `git mv` instead of just `mv` on the command line to move files in a way which preserves more history.

Comment: That's what I figured. But when doing this, there seems to be a [recommended solution using `filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_making_a_subdirectory_the_new_root)